# Scrollbar position problem on location.reload()

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div style='height:2000px;'>please scroll down</div>
<a href=# onclick="location.reload();return false;">Reload Page</a>
<div style='height:1000px;'>...</div>
```

[demo here](http://upload.114good.com/temp/scrolltop.html)

in chrome or firefox,when I click "Reload Page",the page can revert to my scrolltop,

but in IE(6,7,8),they stay on the top

how to implement revert scrolltop effect like chrome in IE?

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scroll` function, here's an example:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Javascript-Objects/WindowscrollExample.htm

Here's an example of `<a>` similar to what you want:

```
<a href="javascript:scroll(0,0)">
Top
</a>
```

You can combine both if you actually want to scroll and reload.

Comment: thanks,but I want to reload page first,then scrollto，how to do?

Comment: Put: `javascript:scroll(0,0);window.location.reload()` in `href`. You cannot do it in the order you want, you need to scroll, then reload, as after reloading you don't have your code executing anymore. You can put `scroll` in page `onLoad` if that is desired.

Comment: put `scroll()` in `onload()` ? any better way to do this?

Comment: When you reload, the only code that will execute is the code from the new page - there's way to continue executing old code.

Comment: yes I know, now I using `location.href='#name'` to implement it,I want a best solution,like a jquery plug-in ? @@

Comment: OK, I don't follow you. With the above comment you actually prevent reloading - do you want to reload or not? If you don't want reloading, just scrolling, just use `scroll` like I described and add return false: `<a href="javascript:scroll(0,0); return false">`. Otherwise, there's no solution other then `onLoad` that I see.